# How do websites such as Tumblr and Wikia assign custom subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5

**I'm using Rails 5 and Nginx, if that's relevant**

I'd like to create a website where a user can be assigned a custom subdomain.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how I'd implement that.

Would the best way be using Rails routing?  Or should this be an Nginx thing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check GoRails https://gorails.com search subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29483146/4515647

Basically:

1. Validate that the property that will be used as a subdomain (e.g. 'name') is not something like 'www'
2. Get models (e.g. `User`) from `request.subdomain` in controller
3. Create a Subdomain class like the following that is autoloaded:

:

```
Class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    case request.subdomain
    when 'www', '', nil
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

4. Configure your routes